# Getting nullPointerException onStart() method on some Android devices

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I don't know why I am getting nullPointerException `OnStart()` method on some devices.
also, I am not able to replicate this exception. Some user's app crashed and when checked that on google console its showing  nullPointerException onStart():

```
protected void onStart() 
{
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onStart(); //Getting Exception Here NullPointerException
}
```

Comment: Do you have stacktrace?

Comment: Actually, I am not able to replicate that exception some of the users faced this issue. its working fine for me

Comment: Is that your whole `onStart` method? If so, it's pointless. But pointlessness wouldn't explain the crash. What class does your activity extend?

Comment: It `extends FragmentActivity` and `implements OnClickListener,
        OnPageChangeListener, CallBackInterFace, SmsObserver.SmsSendListener`

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I am initializing all code in `onCreate()` method Should i Put it in `onStart()`  Method

Answer (score 0):

Your app may have a problem when in recreating progress.

When the app is minimized too long in the background, the system may gains back the memory and clear your resources. Singleton classes, activity instances, and unsaved data are also cleared. When you come back, it tries to recreate the last visible activity and this time a lot of call will get `NullPointerException`.

Reproduce the destroy process follow these steps:

- Put your app into background
- Hit the `Terminate` button in the `Logcat` tab:
- Reopen the app and it may crashes, look for the crash log and fix it

[image]